# Choosing the best SVM kernel type and parameters using OpenCV on Python

Tags: python, opencv, kernel, svm, cross-validation

I'm trying to find the SVM kernel type and parameters that fits better my data. I'm using OpenCV on Python and I found the function [cv2.SVM.train_auto](http://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/mzucker1/opencv-2.4.10-docs/modules/ml/doc/support_vector_machines.html#cvsvm-train-auto) to achieve this, but I didn't found a clear example of how to use it.

Could someone guide me to find the best kernel or give me an explanation of how to use cv2.SVM.train_auto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also looking for that information but you can have a look at the [digits_adjust.py](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/digits_adjust.py) example, it uses `train()` instead of `train_auto()` and shows how to iterate on C and gamma parameters to try to find a best combination.

Interesting functions are:

```
...
def cross_validate(model_class, params, samples, labels, kfold = 3, pool = None):
...
    def adjust_SVM(self):
        Cs = np.logspace(0, 10, 15, base=2)
        gammas = np.logspace(-7, 4, 15, base=2)
...
            params = dict(C = Cs[i], gamma=gammas[j])
            score = cross_validate(SVM, params, samples, labels)
...
```